# Is there a bug when you convert a Number to String in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, numbers

This has happens when I convert a large number to string in Javascript, it seems to give me a result which i do not expect:

> var x=1234567890123456;
>
> console.log(x) //1234567890123456 --equal...
>
> console.log(x.toString()) //1234567890123456 --equal...
>
> var x=12345678901234567;
>
> console.log(x) // 12345678901234568 --different!
>
> console.log(x.toString()) //12345678901234568 --different!
>
> var x=123456789012345678;
>
> console.log(x) //123456789012345680 --different!
>
> console.log(x.toString()) //123456789012345680 --different!
>
> console.log(x+"") //123456789012345680 --different!

Can anyone could tell me the reason for this, and how to deal with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is the maximum of numbers in javascript (+/- 9007199254740992) without losing precision. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t).

Answer (score 3):

Javascript does not have infinite numeric precision.  There is a limit to the number of significant digits that it will keep track of in the 8 byte double precision floating point values.

See the [actual ECMA Number spec section 8.5](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5) for more specific details.  Quoted from that spec:

> Note that all the positive and negative integers whose magnitude is no
>   greater than 2^53 are representable in the Number type

2^53 == 9007199254740992